# Cannot display image from base64 string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, image, base64

I'm trying to display a raw image which has been formatted to base64 into an img element with javascript. I already have my base64 but cannot make it displaying as raw image, what is wrong with the code?

here is the code.

```
 $.each(post.JobPictures, function (i, pictures) {
                                            if (pictures != null) {
                                                var decodedString = atob(pictures.JobImageContentBytes)
                                                var img = new Image();
                                                img.src = ("data:image/jpg;base64,"+ decodedString);

                                                `<div class="separate-pic">
                                                    <img class="posted-pic" src="`+img+`" alt="" />
                                                </div>`
                                             }
                                    })
```

UPDATE THIS IS USING MAP NOW, BUT IT DOES NOT GO IN AT ALL

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SearchByCategory", "AllJobs")',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'JSON',
        data: { category: categoryId },
        success: function (posts) {

            $(".job-container").html("");
            //$(".job-container").load(" .job-container");

            $.each(posts.FindJobs, function (i, post) {

                var newdate = new Date(post.PostedDate + 'Z');
                var day = newdate.getDate();


                $(".job-container").append(`


                        <li class="separate-job" id="All-Jobs-Id" value="` + post.jobId + `">
                            <div class="content-li-All-Jobs">
                                <h2 class="content-li-All-headline" id="headline-for-Update">`+ post.Headline + `</h2>
                                <a class="btn btn-success bid-for-job" value="`+ post.jobId + `" href="#">Bid now</a>
                                <div class="user">
                                    <blockquote class="blockquote">
                                        <p class="mb-0">
                                            <div class="about-job">`+ post.About + `</div>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="blockquote-footer">
                                            <cite>-`+ post.Username + `</cite>
                                        </div>
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pictures-li">
                                   `+ $.map(post.jobPictures, function (i, pictures) {
                        if (pictures != null) {
                            var decodedString = atob(pictures.JobImageContentBytes)
                            return `<div class="separate-pic">
                <img class="posted-pic" src="data:image/jpg;base64,${decodedString}" alt="" />
            </div>`;
                        }
                    }).join("") + `
                                </div>

                                <div class="job-date-li">
                                    Posted `+ newdate.getDate() + ` ` + newdate.getMonth() + ` ` + newdate.getFullYear() + 
                `

                                </div>
                                <div class="-job-town">Area | <span class="city">`+ post.JobCity+`</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>



                 `)

            });



        }
    });
```

This is my entire ajax call which I make to a controller in order to get all jobs which are in certain category and create those divs and assign the relevant data to them

here is the image that shows that the object/arrays are not empty

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Taplar sorry, my bad, I was using the following code snippet in an .append method. Now it is more clear?

Comment: So, basically, I have an array with some bytes and I loop through the items to display the img and create div+ img element. How else should I do it? I`m really confused

Comment: @Taplar I don't want to do anything with it - All I want to do is to display the img inside a div and depending on how long the array is it will generate those divs with those images.

Comment: I will update the post to see the whole append and what`s in it...

Comment: Ok, major major code smell.  Why are you sticking an entire `$.map()` inside a template literal?  Don't do that dude.  Pull that out, generate your html into a variable, and then use that variable in your template literal.  And keep in mind a point I made on the answer below, that trying to append an `Image` object to an html `String` is most likely going to cause issues.  You have to get the html for the image, so you may have to grab the `outerHTML` off it, if the Image implements that.

Comment: just copied the code from the below answer to check If it is working, but it isn`t, whereas with $.each it was showing as you said, object-object. It is not a good idea to do it like this?

Comment: Ok - I will try to workaround to see what I can do

Comment: @Taplar when you say to generate the html into a variable what exactly do you mean? to generate the specific html that the $.map returns and then put the variable in the appent method?

Comment: Look at the answer below.  Rather than creating an `Image`, it's just generating the html.

Comment: `contentType: 'JSON',` is wrong, it should be `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @Barmar noted! Thanks for this :) Any ideas why this is still not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.each()` returns the value of its first argument, so this will by equivalent to just writing:

```
+ post.JobPictures +
```

You need to use `$.map()`, the callback function needs to return something, and then you can concatenate the array of results into a string with `.join()`.

You shouldn't try to concatenate an `img` element directly into the string. Instead, substitute the base64 string into the `src` attribute.

The data in `JobImageContentBytes is already encoded as base64, you don't need to call anything to encode it.

`JobPictures` has an uppercase `J` at the beginning.

The arguments to the callback function of `$.map` should be in the order `element`, `index`.

```
+ $.map(post.JobPictures, function (pictures) {
    if (pictures != null) {
        return `<div class="separate-pic">
                    <img class="posted-pic" src="data:image/jpg;base64,${pictures.JobImageContentBytes}" alt="" />
                </div>`;
     }
}).join("") +
```

BTW, the point of using template literals is so you don't need to end the string and use `+` to concatenate an expression, you can embed the expression with `${}`. So don't write

```
src="`+img+`"
```

Instead write

```
src="${img}"
```

Comment: Comments [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192988/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-cannot-display-image-from-base64-string-in-javasc).